# Grails: Loading gsps from database

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, gsp

I have a Grails application that allow internal users send mails using the Grails mail plugin.

The mail content is generated from gsps. Values like dates and names are interpolated.

Now, I would like the application to allow the users to edit the mail templates without having to change the gsps myself and redeploy the application.

Would it be possible to store and load the gsps in/from database, making possible for the users to edit the mail templates at runtime, while keeping the possibility to have variable interpolation in the template?

Comment: Simply use <b>WYSIWYG HTML Editor</b> which generate HTML from design. save that generated HTML code to DB. and while displaying render from db

Comment: yes! (this is the answer your question implies)